# How did Michael erode the iron pipe to the infirmary?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

How did Michael do the chemistry work in *Prison Break* S1E4 'cute poison'?

Which substances did he mix that included toothpaste and poured them into the tube in the infirmary and acquired a "compound" that eroded the iron?

Comment: Since 'cute poison' is an episode name of Prison Break, I took `the-prisoner` tag off this.

Comment: Related answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35324/does-cute-poison-actually-work

Comment: CuSo4 is the cute poison with H3PO4 AFAIR

Comment: IIRC, the compound didn't use toothpaste, he used the toothpaste tube to hide the actual compound he used after pouring all of Haywire's toothpaste down the drain.